# Submit basic HTML form using Postman

Tags: forms, postman

I am trying to log into [this website](https://www.daiseywilks.com/login/) using Postman.
[image]

There is no username and this is what the HTML look like:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="loginbox">
            <img id="logo" src="../gfx/logo.png" alt="" />
            <form action="" method="POST">
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <p id="message">
                &nbsp;
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This my POST request on Postman and I am not getting any `"Wrong password.`" html back so I guess I am not doing the correct thing. How can I make a POST request to login using Postman?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form includes two values, `password` *and* `submit`.  The latter has no value associated with it, but the key is still being posted to the server.

It seems that the server-side code is using the `submit` key to trigger its logic.  Just include that in your form data with no value.

Answer (score 2):

Giving a "submit" key as empty in addition to the password field is needed . Please refer the sample request image given.

[image]